# .htaccess URL redirect but not displaying index page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

After searching for a answer for my issue, I'm still stumped on this. I'm working on a small social script that allows users to create profiles, but I want their URL to their profile to be short. I edited the .htaccess file and it works perfectly!

For example
    www.site.com/username
Redirecting to 
    www.site.com/profile.php?user=username

However, when you just go to the index page. It shows profile.php but with an empty GET variable...

here is my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is location of this `.htaccess` and where are `profile.php and index.php` files located?

Comment: the main directory(/public_html). Do they need to be in separate directories? Really hoping to make it www.site.com/username and not www.site.com/profile/username

Comment: `Are profile.php and index.php also in the main directory(/public_html).?`

Comment: Yes, all the files are in the same directory.

Comment: I would say: Use `^(.+)$` instead. This requires at least 1 character to be present. Assuming the server is configured correctly to show `index.php` etc when you request a directory, it now should show the index page for `http://site.url/`.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have a problem when going to address: http://www.site.com/ (not www.site.com/index.php). And .htaccess see than file "" doesn't exists and redirects to www.site.com/profile.php?user= (with empty parameter user). Try modyfy .htaccess to this (use `^(.+)$` instead `^(.*)$`):

> ```
> RewriteEngine One
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^(.+)$ profile.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ profile.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Having `/?` would also prevent any trailing slash (if present).